# AHK GUI DateTime default setting

Tags: javascript, c++, autohotkey

Is there a way to set display the dateTime control as blank when loading?

I have

```
  class DateTime extends Tabs.Tab.Workspace.GenericControl
        {
            ControlType := "DateTime"
            DefaultOptions := "ChooseNone"
            New()
            {MsgBox, % this.GuiControlGet()
             }
            DateTimeChanged(_CtrlHwnd, _GuiEvent, _EventInfo, _ErrorLevel:="")
            {
             MsgBox, % this.GuiControlGet()
            }
            Clear()
            {
                this.GuiControl("", A_Now)
                this.GuiControl("", "")
                this.GuiControl("", "")
            }




        }
```

Or

```
          ControlType := "DateTime"
            DefaultOptions := "Choose20200202"
```

The chooseNone default still displays todays date, which is fine except when transferring the values to a worksheet the value is still transferred even the the box is unchecked in the control.

The code that transfers the values to the worksheet.

```
WorkbookPopulate(MyWorkbook, TabsObj) {
    for TabNumber, ThisTab in TabsObj.TabList {
        for ControlType, ThisControlType in ThisTab.Workspace.Controls {
            ; Special case: skip the TabOrder object TODO maybe this should be rethought? On
            ; the other hand, this simplifies adding controls to the TabOrder
            if (ControlType = "TabOrder")
                    continue
            for ControlName, ThisControl in ThisControlType {
                if (ThisControl.ExcelCell != "") {
                    MyValue := ThisControl.GuiControlGet()
                    ; Change MyValue as a special case for Checkboxes
                    if (ControlType = "Checkbox") {
                        ;~ MyValue := MyValue = 1 ? "a" : "c" ; Use "Marlett" font in template
                        MyValue := MyValue = 1 ? Chr(0x2713) : "" ;Chr(0x2610)
                                                ;Chr(0x2610) - BALLOT BOX
                                                ;Chr(0x2611) - BALLOT BOX WITH CHECK
                                                ;Chr(0x2612) - BALLOT BOX WITH X
                                                ;Chr(0x2713) - CHECK MARK
                                                ;Chr(0x2714) - HEAVY CHECK MARK
                    }
                    if (ControlType = "DateTime")
                    FormatTime, MyValue, %MyValue%, MMMM dd, yyyy
                    MyWorkbook.Sheets(ThisControl.ExcelSheet).Range(ThisControl.ExcelCell).Value
                        := MyValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What would be great is just to have the MyValue "--" if no date was selected(Checked).
The other option I was looking to do is to have the default to "---"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in AHK:

```
checkbox=0 ;var to keep track of the checkbox status. 1 = checked / 0 = unchecked
Gui, Add, DateTime, vDateTimeVar 2 ChooseNone gcheck, -- ;2 adds the checkbox. ChooseNone defaults it to unchecked
Gui, Show
return

check:
if (checkbox=1) ; if checked
{
    GuiControl, Text, DateTimeVar, -- ;Changes to "--"
    checkbox=0
}
else
{
    GuiControl, Text, DateTimeVar, M/d/yy HH:mm ;Changes the format to M/d/yy HH:mm
    Guicontrol,, DateTimeVar, %a_now% ;Set's current date
    checkbox=1
}
return
```

You need to change the format to "--" with GuiControl, Text then you change it back to your desired DateTime format, and after that you change it's value to the Date you want.